# set matlab figure larger than screen

Tags: matlab, resize, matlab-figure, figure

I would like to set a figure's dimensions to be larger than the screen size, e.g.:

```
hf = figure('Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [0 0 2000 1500]);
```

but as my screen size is 1920x1080, the figure is automatically rescaled to a size that fits my screen.

What could be done to prevent this rescaling?

Comment: Is this for printing purposes? [This MATLAB Central thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/308834) may be useful.

Comment: @excaza: came across that thread (and many others) before posting the question here )). I want a fixed amount of real-estate to produce a bunch of subplots. This way, I know the figure will look the same when moving from my laptop to the workstation. Also would gain reproducibility in saving figures when running matlab with different displays.

Comment: If you want the figure to look the same you're probably better off using `'Normalized'` units.

Comment: That's what I used originally, but it doesn't cut it. If a monitor has 1920x1200 and I run the same script in a display only capable of 1920x1080, the figure is distorted vertically, especially the axes and labels. I require the script to produce the same results independently of the display. Very interestingly, if in Linux I set Visibility='off', I can then change the Position to a value larger than the screen size (and even print  the figure to a file, conserving the number of pixels). Doesn't work in Windows, though.

Comment: it always worked for me and i just used the command you posted and it still worked on my machine (Win7,2016a) is ist always spread to the entire monitor or just capped in the dimension that would be to big?

Comment: @Finn: Interesting! Just after I use the command in the question, the Position field in the figure handle is set automatically to: Position: [2 26 1918 948] (Linux R2016a); If I do it Win8.1 R2016a, the Position is [0 0 1918 1001].  I suppose the difference between Win and Linux is because of the Menu/Toolbar size. Also happens in win10, R2012a. The values only get capped for the dimensions that would exceed screen size (excluding the size of other window components).

Comment: that is wierd behaviour and as you mentioned it seems to be independent from matlab version and os. i tried it here on an other machine (win10,2015) and it acts as on my machine. some additional questions: is it just the figure or is it part of some larger program(like just starting matlab and hitting the command)? does it happen also for width? what happend if you outscale the windown manualy?

Comment: I just start matlab and hit the command. You're on to something here. If I manually move the window partially out of the screen, then I can resize it (both manually and by setting its Position), even for values larger than the screen size, i.e., the figure exists outside the screen. Unfortunately, if I create a second figure, the issue still occurs for the new figure. This trick only works in Linux, though! In Win8.1, I am not even able to manually increase the size of the window beyond screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this was fixed in 2017a (or a little earlier) since this code work just fine on Win10:

```
screen = get(0,'ScreenSize');
f = figure('Units', 'pixels','Position',screen*2);
```

The resulted figure is indeed bigger than the screen:

```
>> screen
screen =
           1           1        1920        1080    
>> f.Position
ans =
           2           2        3828         991
```

Comment: Tried it again on 2017b and 2017a on Win 8.1
After running your lines, f.Position gives me [2         124        1916         999]

Comment: @serigado It's a problem with Windows versions that are not Win 10. I have tried it on Win Server 2012 with Matlab 2017a and got a result similar to yours.